# Select 2 fails to work, Cant pinpoint the reason

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, jquery-select2

i've got a razor page,
With the following :

```
@section renderHead{
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>    
}
```

The Dropdown :

```
<div id="multiplySelect" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            @if (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.WriterList) == 0)
            {
                @Html.DropDownList("multipleWriters", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WriterList, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", disabled = "disabled" })
                <label id="error" class="form_label_comment">אין קטגוריות קיימות.</label>
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DropDownList("multipleWriters", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WriterList, new { @class = "form-control", data_val = "false", multiple = "multiple", style = "width:100%;" })
            }
        </div>
```

And the Select2 Execution (inside a script tag ofcourse):

```
$('multipleWriters').select2({
        language: "he",
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: {
            "id": "",
            "text": ''
        },
    });
```

A bit lost, At the moment i get an open dropdown which looks nothing like Select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the selector `$('multipleWriters')` is wrong

To select by id Must be  (note the `#` in front)

```
$('#multipleWriters')
```

or to select by class `$('.classname')` if you use class name (note the dot `.` in front)